# Need to parse text out of a long string in sql server

Tags: sql

The text I need to retrieve out of the ntext below is **"elapsedTime":83775**

{"timeline":{"events":[{"date":1593613822828,"types":["START"]},{"date":1593613906603,"types":["STOP"]}]},"ongoingSLAData":null,"completeSLAData":[{"succeeded":true,"goalTime":57600000,"goalTimeUnits":{"weeks":0,"remainingDaysWithinWeek":1,"remainingMillisWithinDay":28800000,"breached":false},"elapsedTime":83775,"remainingTime":57516225,"remainingTimeInDaysAndMillis":{"weeks":0,"remainingDaysWithinWeek":1,"remainingMillisWithinDay":28716225,"breached":false},"calendarName":"Sample 9-5 Calendar","startTime":1593613822828,"stopTime":1593613906603}],"metricId":48,"definitionChangeDate":0,"definitionChangeMsEpoch":0,"goalsChangeDate":null,"goalsChangeMsEpoch":null,"goalTimeUpdatedDate":null,"goalTimeUpdatedMsEpoch":null,"metricCreatedDate":1593021654383,"updatedDate":1593657022772}

Comment: the elapsed time amount can vary. 

I know this is in JSON format. I may have to use a powerBI to query this column.

Comment: Hello Cameron. you should edit your question to quote your code so it's more readable. Are you interested in getting the complete value or only the 83775 value ?

Answer (score 0):

Not nice.

Assuming that there is always exactly one occurrence of `elapsedTime`:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(1000) = '{"timeline":{"events":[{"date":1593613822828,"types":["START"]},{"date":1593613906603,"types":["STOP"]}]},"ongoingSLAData":null,"completeSLAData":[{"succeeded":true,"goalTime":57600000,"goalTimeUnits":{"weeks":0,"remainingDaysWithinWeek":1,"remainingMillisWithinDay":28800000,"breached":false},"elapsedTime":83775,"remainingTime":57516225,"remainingTimeInDaysAndMillis":{"weeks":0,"remainingDaysWithinWeek":1,"remainingMillisWithinDay":28716225,"breached":false},"calendarName":"Sample 9-5 Calendar","startTime":1593613822828,"stopTime":1593613906603}],"metricId":48,"definitionChangeDate":0,"definitionChangeMsEpoch":0,"goalsChangeDate":null,"goalsChangeMsEpoch":null,"goalTimeUpdatedDate":null,"goalTimeUpdatedMsEpoch":null,"metricCreatedDate":1593021654383,"updatedDate":1593657022772}'

DECLARE @i int
SELECT @i = CHARINDEX('elapsedTime":', @s)

DECLARE @j int
SELECT @j = CHARINDEX(',', @s, @i + 13)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, @i + 13, @j - @i - 13)
```

Or, since it's JSON:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@s, '$.completeSLAData[0].elapsedTime')
```

Comment: Thanks! Single quotes must not be proper JSON format? I'll have to replace those with double quotes.